# Align and equation do not work in standalone

Tags: math-mode, errors, align, amsmath, standalone

I am trying to use align and equation in standalone, but I get compiler errors even in the most basic of examples. For example,

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
     a = 1 \\
     b=2
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

Gives

```
  1 a.tex|10 error| Missing \endgroup inserted.                                                         
  2 a.tex|10 error| Missing } inserted.
  3 a.tex|10 warning| Overfull \hbox (23.61913pt too wide) detected at line 10
  4 a.tex|10 error| LaTeX Error: \begin{document} ended by \end{align}.
  5 a.tex|10 error| Missing $ inserted.
  6 a.tex|10 error| Display math should end with $$.
  7 a.tex|10 error| Extra \endgroup.
  8 a.tex|12 error| Too many }'s.
```

Similar results with align*, equation, aligned. I as soon as I change the documentclass from standalone to article, it works. I'm sure I am making a silly error here. My platform is Debian, using the TexLive Full package(up to date).

edit: If I move the align block outside the document block, I get no errors(but of course, the pdf is empty)

Comment: You'll probably need the varwidth option for standalone. Note that it will probably have a lot of horizontal excessive white space

Answer (score 5):

I think you're mis-using, and maybe even abusing,  the `standalone` package. According to the user guide of the `standalone` package, the main (sole?) purpose of the `standalone` package is to generate well-contained objects -- often, but not exclusively, pictures -- that can be saved as external files in a suitable file format for subsequent pasting into other documents, e.g., Word and PowerPoint files. It is not designed to generate displayed single-line or multi-line equations via `equation` or `align` environments. While it is *possible* to generate some output by setting the document class option `varwidth`, it's far from optimal.

If you wish to create a displayed single-line or multi-line equation, you should probably use a `aligned` environment in inline math mode. E.g.,

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
$\begin{aligned}
     a &= 1 \\
     b &= 2
\end{aligned}$
\end{document}
```

compiles fine.